# Google sheet SUMIF's fixed range issue

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I am trying to apply the formula for `sumif`'s based on a fixed range, and I cannot get results.

**Screenshots of issue:**

- https://ibb.co/dZygvL
- https://ibb.co/ng4X20

*I am required level 10 reputation to be able to post images so sorry for the inconvenience. I just included links for images.*

**Formula:**

`=sumifs($D$2:$D$1000 , $C$2:$C$1000 , "Done", $E$2:$E$1000 , "Waqas")`

**Does anyone know why this formula is not returning a sum?**

Comment: formula is not visible in images above so i am including formula down here in comments : 

=sumifs($D$2:$D$1000 , $C$2:$C$1000 , "Done", $E$2:$E$1000 , "Waqas")

Comment: I dont see any problem with the function. Do you have any extra characters in cells with text "done" or "Waqas"? Is it that the hours column doesnt have proper numbers? Try checking it with a smaller set such as d1:d5 instead of d1:d100?

Comment: nope i don't have any extra characters the values i have cross checked they are already binded as drop down lists to have fixed values for columns C and E and i have also tried by narrowing down the range it still doesn't work but if sum of range function is working fine for bigger range sumif's shouldn't it work too with bigger range even though i have already checked no the format of the data types in columns and everything seems to be in order

Comment: You may try copying the value of "Done" and "Waqas" from C2 and E2 respectively, into formula than to type it. See if that changes anything?

Comment: have tried doing that as well but no luck below is shareable link for the sheet and please find the sheet by the title of testing....
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14F5aCDNSr3SkudzVwLfzJVPHprg7G-34NrkepNrmfu0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see 28.3333 and 1.333 based on `sumifs`, which I think is correct. What exactly is the problem you are seeing with the formula and what result do you expect? I am sorry, I am not able to open the image at work.

Comment: Going on the shared doc, Sprint tab, I see sumif not sumifs. Did something change? By the way, you could use the UNIQUE function to list the workers without having to key them in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" formula actually works just fine. But it has a flaw: it can't be easily copied down the column to apply to other workers. A generic version of the formula is `=sumifs($D$2:$D , $C$2:$C , "Done", $E$2:$E , F5)` where `F5` is the name of the worker. Note, this also provides for infinite column lengths.

Another option is that the OP could list the names of workers by using `=sort(unique(E2:E))`. While the OP may need a longer list for other purposes, this shouldn't stop using a function to pickup names from a master list.